# PushNotification: How do I disable sound when user receives notification from server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, audio

I am wondering if it is possible if user ever receives a push notification from the server if you can turn off the sound within the App. I never register `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound` in my App, yet when the App is in background the notification can still be heard. I do register badge and alert however. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you control the server?  That's where the sound is designated.

Comment: Well, not exactly but I can tell the API guy about it. I guess I can do something about the Sound from the server.

Comment: Is there any recommendation on how I should go about this? I don't know how to go about this 100 percent. Is there a way I can activate the sound without the server?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I think the right way to go is to let this be a user pref saved at the server.  The server can tell the push to go with/without sound based on that pref.